# iOS 7 Collection View inside Scroll View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm using storyboard to develop an application that has a `UICollectionView` inside an `UIScrollView`.
I've set the delegate and `dataSource` in storyboard and code.

I'm putting fake information to verify the layout of the app but `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` not appear in any way.

**.M**

```
@implementation PerfilUsuarioViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title =  @"Perfil";
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fundo@2X.png"]];
    FotosHelper* fotoCasal = [[FotosHelper alloc]init];

    //Tamanho da view que sera exibida
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(310, 1160);
    //Tamanho da tela do aparelho
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

    [self preparaZPositionCamposDetalhesCasal];
    [self dadosPessoaUm];

    self.fotosCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.fotosCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    self.labelNmCasal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%ld)", self.usuario.usuarioNome, self.usuario.usuarioCodigo];
    self.fotoCasal.image = [fotoCasal decodeBase64ToImage:self.usuario.usuarioFotoPerfil];
    self.fieldProposta.text = self.usuario.usuarioDescricao;
}

//inner methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        TituloCollectionViewCell *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"headerView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *title = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%i", indexPath.section + 1];
        headerView.labelTitulo.text = title;

        reusableview = headerView;
    }
    return reusableview;
}


(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FotosCollectionViewCell *cell = (FotosCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.fotoCollectionViewCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"feminino.png"];

    if (cell.selected) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    FotosCollectionViewCell *datasetCell = (FotosCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FotosCollectionViewCell *datasetCell = (FotosCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
}

</code>
```

**.H**

```
<code>
@interface PerfilUsuarioViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
</code>
```

Comment: UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView. You should not use UIScrollView subclasses inside a UIScrollView container because they will have issues capturing touches and applying the proper action to gestures. UICollectionViewCells are to be used inside UICollectionViews only.

Comment: Are you actually trying to put a `UICollectionViewCell` in a `UIScrollView`? Or are you trying to embed a collection view inside a scrollview?

Comment: Sorry, I'm putting a UICollectionView inside a ScrollView and in the UICollectionView I putting UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Why are you putting a UICollectionView inside a UIScrollView? That's seems like a pretty weird UI...

Comment: I have a screen where you can view the profile of a User.
One of the fields is a list of photos, this list of photos is a UICollectionViewCell

Comment: @CaptJak What's so weird about a collection view in a scroll view?

Comment: @Anholon Are the datasource methods being called?

Comment: @Sebastian 
-numberOfSectionsInCollectionView is called

-numberOfItemsInSection is called

-cellForItemAtIndexPath no called

Comment: @Sebastian, whats not weird? I don't really understand how that would go... what else is in the scrollView? Why put it in a scrollView?

Comment: @CaptJak You could have multiple vertically scrolling collection views in a horizontally scrolling (paged) scroll view. Like the spring board.

Comment: I don't think Springboard is multiple collectionViews. Just one with page scrolling. See: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uicollectionview-layouts/

Comment: @CaptJak I didn't say that it was made that way, it's just one way of making something like springboard. This is off topic though, so we shouldn't discuss this here any further.

Comment: @Sebastian, true. But I still don't know what he is trying to do. The original comment that I posted was actually meant for the OP... He has not answered any of my questions. My point is that what he is trying to do seems incorrect and that there might be an easier and faster way of accomplishing his goal.

Comment: I understand that this should not be the simplest way to do what I want, anyone have any idea how to display a User's profile that has a list of photos?

Comment: Just use UICollectionView. It will scroll automatically if the number of cells exceeds the bounds of the view. Something like this: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial.

Comment: I think only the UICollectionView not solve my problem.
Link of layout.
In place of UICollectionView should upload the pictures of the User.

http://upload.crazzy.com.br/show-image.php?id=b5f2c5690344cde6d4bb0192ad54118f